# Making the rows of a data frame to NAs using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I have a data frame as follows,

```
aid=c(1:10)
x1_var=rnorm(10,0,1)
x2_var=rnorm(10,0,1)
x3_var=rbinom(10,1,0.5)

data=data.frame(aid,x1_var,x2_var,x3_var)


 head(data)
  aid      x1_var     x2_var x3_var
1   1 -0.99759448 -0.2882535      1
2   2 -0.12755695 -1.3706875      0
3   3  1.04709366  0.8977596      1
4   4  0.48883458 -0.1965846      1
5   5 -0.40264114  0.2925659      1
6   6 -0.08409966 -1.3489460      1
```

I want to make the all the rows in this data frame completely to `NA` if `x3_var==1`(without making `aid` column to `NA`)

I tried the following code.

```
 > data[which(data$x3_var==1),]=NA
> data
   aid      x1_var     x2_var x3_var
1   NA          NA         NA     NA
2    2 -0.12755695 -1.3706875      0
3   NA          NA         NA     NA
4   NA          NA         NA     NA
5   NA          NA         NA     NA
6   NA          NA         NA     NA
7   NA          NA         NA     NA
8    8 -1.78160459 -1.8677633      0
9    9 -1.65895704 -0.8086148      0
10  10 -0.06281384  1.8888726      0
```

But this code have made the values of aid column also to NA. Can anybody help me to fix this?

Also are there any methods that do the same thing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would work if you remove `aid` column from it.

```
data[which(data$x3_var==1),-1]=NA
```

You can also do this without `which` :

```
data[data$x3_var==1, -1]=NA
```

In the above two cases I am assuming that you know the position of `aid` column i.e 1. If in reality you don't know the position of the column you can use `match` to get it's position.

```
data[data$x3_var==1, -match('aid', names(data))] = NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution. Assuming the columns to be altered begin with "x" as in the example data.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1001)
df1 <- data.frame(aid = 1:10,
                  x1_var = rnorm(10,0,1),
                  x2_var = rnorm(10,0,1),
                  x3_var = rbinom(10,1,0.5))

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("x"), ~ifelse(x3_var == 1, NA, .x)))

   aid     x1_var     x2_var x3_var
1    1  2.1886481  0.3026445      0
2    2 -0.1775473  1.6343924      0
3    3         NA         NA     NA
4    4 -2.5065362  0.4671611      0
5    5         NA         NA     NA
6    6 -0.1435595  0.1102652      0
7    7         NA         NA     NA
8    8 -0.6229437 -1.0302508      0
9    9         NA         NA     NA
10  10         NA         NA     NA
```